# CMake doesn't pass CUDA arguments?

Tags: cmake, cuda, clang

I am trying to compile a library with both, C++ and CUDA source files. I am using GNU make with CMake. My compiler of choice is clang, since CUDA only supports gcc up to version 5 and Debian 9 has gcc 6 as its oldest version and I have to use software that is provided by the Debian 9 or 10 repositories.

CMake version is 3.9.0
clang version is 3.8.1

cc and c++ in /usr/bin correctly link to clang and clang++ ẃhich also link to the correct files.

Unfortunately the initial checks of CMake for CUDA fail although everything, as far as I can see, seems to be set up correctly. It looks like the arguments aren't passed correctly to the CUDA compiler.

This is a part of my project's main CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project (dev)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILATION_CPP ON)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets -ccbin clang-3.8")
```

The library's CMake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project (libname LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cu" "*.cpp")

add_library(libname ${SOURCES})

set_target_properties(libname PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set_target_properties(libname PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

This is the output of CMake:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found CUDA: /usr (found version "8.0") 
-- The CUDA compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/bin/nvcc -- broken
```

The CUDA/nvcc tests of CMake fails with the following errors:

```
  Change Dir: /home/user/projects/hamonIC-linux-experimental/current_state/working_copy/code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_6d1a9/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_6d1a9.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_6d1a9.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/home/user/projects/hamonIC-linux-experimental/current_state/working_copy/code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6d1a9.dir/main.cu.o

  /usr/bin/nvcc -x cu -c
  /home/user/projects/hamonIC-linux-experimental/current_state/working_copy/code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/main.cu
  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6d1a9.dir/main.cu.o

  nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are
  deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use
  -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).

  ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is
  available.

         Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead.

  CMakeFiles/cmTC_6d1a9.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
  'CMakeFiles/cmTC_6d1a9.dir/main.cu.o' failed

  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_6d1a9.dir/main.cu.o] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/home/user/projects/hamonIC-linux-experimental/current_state/working_copy/code/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


  Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_6d1a9/fast' failed

  make: *** [cmTC_6d1a9/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hic_iplibrary/source/ciccommon/CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA NVCC flags in CMake have to be semicolon delimited and not whitespace delimited.

Change the flags in your `CMakeLists.txt` to use:

`set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets;-ccbin=clang-3.8")`

and that should allow CMake to pass your flags to NVCC.